# Vim YouCompleteMe Python subclasses are not detected on TAB-completion in Arch Linux

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin, archlinux, tab-completion

I can TAB-complete current open file variables, paths & globals, but my python subclasses are not detected on TAB completion. For instance,

```
import os          # os is built-in library.
os.                # ycm does not complete members of this class.
```

It has been 48h that I'm searching the solution. My /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.7, all the tests pass 100% and the build was successful.

```
> uname -r
4.0.5-1-ARCH
```

I tried installing packages specific to Arch Linux from repositories and they don't seem to work.

At this point, I think my best chance would be to find the place where the python path or a variable with this purpose is set in the original package for Vundle, YouCompleteMe. Then, I should be able to verify that it is correct. I am open to all possible solutions or insights on this issue.

```
> echo $PYTHONPATH

/usr/lib/python2.7/
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you try to install `jedi` to determin whether it's `jedi` or `YouCompleteMe` issue? YCM was written with C/C++ in mind, its python completion might not be well supported. I remember having the same issue over 2 years ago so if it was important to the developer or the community around YCM, it would have been fixed by now.

Comment: @CyprianGuerra http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233669/jedi-vim-python-subclasses-are-not-detected-on-tab-completion-in-arch-linux

Answer (score 0):

YouCompleteMe relies on Jedi-Vim for python completion.

I just found that it was due to an incomprehension error that I described for Jedi Vim [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31573787/3161360). However, with YouCompleteMe plug-in only few methods shows up on:

```
from os import getc
```

Then I pressed **ctrl + space** and a complete list of available modules was displayed.