# Jedi Vim Python subclasses are not detected on TAB-completion

Tags: python, linux, vim, tab-completion, jedi-vim

The issue is on Arch (1) & Debian Jessie (2) where:

1.

```
> uname -r
4.0.5-1-ARCH
> echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/lib/python2.7/
```

2. Debian Jessie is without the PYTHONPATH set.

My vim is compiled with python.

```
:python import sys; print(sys.version)
2.7.10 (default, May 26 2015, 04:16:29)
[GCC 5.1.0]
```

I tried the following Arch Linux packages:

```
> pacman -S python2-jedi vim-jedi
```

completion works on classes but not on the subclasses.

```
import os          # os is built-in library.
os.                # ycm does not complete members of this class.
```

I removed them and downloaded the git package.

```
> cd ~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/test/ && ./run.py
Summary: (0 fails of 962 tests) in 18.819s

> cd ../ && ./setup build && ./setup install
```

And again,  completion works on classes but not on the subclasses.

My previous question that sent me to jedi-vim from [Vim YouCompleteMe Python subclasses are not detected on TAB-completion in Arch Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228868/vim-youcompleteme-python-subclasses-are-not-detected-on-tab-completion-in-arch-l)

Comment: Could you provide `:mes`, `:scriptnames`, `:set omnifunc` after using the completion once?
BTW: jedi-vim and YCM are both using Jedi under the hood.

Comment: Thank for your time. Yes, I'm aware that jedi-vim and YCM both rely on Jedi. I posted in both to gain visibility. Here is the output http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mk8gxDzb

Comment: Strange, my `:scriptnames` has quite a few more things of jedi-vim that are loaded, among them `jedi-vim/autoload/jedi.vim`, which should definitely be in there.

Comment: I think it is loaded at 14:. Also, after one completion I have a different output. Look at 14, 25, 26, 28, 31 from my new output http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9mDXfbLM. Both of this outputs are from Debian Jessie.

Comment: Now I see. But `:messages` stays empty after one completion?

Comment: @DaveHalter Yes. Out of curiosity, on which system are you running your vim with Jedi?

Comment: On Ubuntu. But I ran it on Debian a while ago. People I know run it on Arch, Windows and Mac and I'm pretty sure on a lot of other Linux Distros.

Comment: @DaveHalter You seem to be the author of Jedi. How does the plugin reference the Python site-packages etc.? Is it possible that it is a referenced path issue? In this case, it would be great if it was possible to define it during the setup.

Comment: It takes the `sys.path`, as defined by Python itself. Maybe the `sys.path` has been modified in your case.

Comment: @DaveHalter I just realized that it was due to my incomprehension. Check my answer below!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the research!

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that I did an error due to my incomprehension. I was trying to import the following way:

[image: wrongway]

Which was natural when I used ipython with tab completion like this:

[image: ipython]

That is a wrong way to import a module in a python script. This is the right way:

[image: rightway]

Finally, the Jedi-Vim plug-in works perfectly. In case of uncertainty related to unavailable imports you can verify your imports with:

```
:python import sys; print(sys.path)
```

And then add the missing directories during the run time to test if their absence was causing the issue.

```
:python import sys; sys.path.append("/path/to/dir")
```

In my case the *os.py* was located at */usr/lib/python2.7/*.

I hope this clarifies this for the future Jedi-Vim users.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I've found an alternative to amending `sys.path` if you are using virtual environments.

You can instead create a `.pth` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) file in your `<virtualenv>/lib/<python>/site-packages` folder that points to the root of your source e.g. if my source was in `/user/123/python-proj/source` folder and my virtual env was in the `/user/123/python-proj/venv` folder

```
echo '/user/123/python-proj/source > /user/123/python-proj/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/my-source.pth'
```

Make sure you activate the virtual env first, then launch vim and jedi should be able to find your code.